# Microsoft Outlook Calendar conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conditional-formatting, calendar

In outlook calendar, view settings, conditional settings,
Is there a way to change the color of meetings I created but did not send out yet?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

> In outlook calendar, view settings, conditional settings, Is there a way to change the color of meetings I created but did not send out yet?

Not feasible using the built-in features available in Outlook.

If you are looking for an easier way to find all unsent meeting requests, you can take a look at the link below to list all your unsent meetings:

[How to find an unsent meeting in Outlook?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/7205-outlook-find-unsent-meeting.html)
[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I will take a look.  I cannot upvote your answer till I get 15 points.

Comment: No worries :-) Just give it a shot at your convenience.